# Joined table not returning any results

Tags: php, sql, join

I successfully joined tables in another part of my code so I followed the same pattern but this time it is not returning any result and I don't understand why.

Here are the tables I am trying to join :

**- roles**

```
| id |  type  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | admin  |
|  2 | author |
|  3 | member |
+----+--------+
```

**- users**

```
+----+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+--------+
| id | username | email | password |      role_id      | status |
+----+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+--------+
|    |          |       |          | 3 (default value) |        |
+----+----------+-------+----------+-------------------+--------+
```

And here is the request :

```
public function get_users()
{
    $users_list = $this->dbh->query('SELECT users.id, roles.id AS roleid, type, role_id, id, username FROM users LEFT JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.id ORDER BY id ASC');
    return $users_list;
}
```

Comment: Try that: `$users_list = $this->dbh->query('SELECT * FROM users AS users LEFT JOIN roles AS roles ON users.id = roles.id ORDER BY id ASC');`

Comment: it's still showing no results. Here is the pattern I follow ```SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;``` but I guess I mistyped something, I'll check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both 2 tables have id column, it is required to specify which table is referring by `<table_name>.id`

```
public function get_users()
{
    $users_list = $this->dbh->query('SELECT users.id AS userid, roles.id AS roleid, type, role_id, username FROM users LEFT JOIN roles ON users.role_id = roles.id ORDER BY users.id ASC');
    return $users_list;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave unexpectedly. Your solution works ! Thanks for the help and I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @CharlèneC, you're welcome. If you don't mind, would you please also vote my answer up? Thanks ^_^

Answer (score 0):

SQL should be

```
SELECT  
    u.id, 
    r.id AS roleid, 
    u.type,
    r.username
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN roles r ON r.id = u.role_id
ORDER BY u.id ASC
```

I've omitted a few of the columns you've defined in the sql you have as I simply don't see the point in them. Not only that but they may seem ambiguous.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    users.id,             // User ID
    roles.id AS roleid,   // Role ID
    type,                 // User type
    role_id,              // Role ID (We already have it, no need for it again)
    id,                   // What ID? This is ambiguous and will fail 
    username              // User Username
```

Comment: I tried with you solution but it's still returning a blank page
I understand what you mean with the ambiguous columns, I will rework on that first

Comment: @CharlèneC When selecting from multiple tables in a join, you should always prefix the column you want using the table as this way you can avoid this issue. Not only this but then you know exactly what table the data is coming from

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public function get_users()
    {
        $users_list = $this->dbh->query('SELECT u.id AS userid, r.id AS roleid, r.type, u.role_id, u.username FROM users as u LEFT JOIN roles as r ON u.role_id = r.id ORDER BY u.id ASC');
        return $users_list;
    }
```

Comment: What changed? What is the answer?